# Como eliminar punto y caracteres hacia la izquierda en c#

Tags: c#, string, xamarin.forms

Tengo unos detalles al querer descomponer un `string` ya que necesito quitar el punto.

Por ejemplo yo recibo desde un webservices el siguiente string

```
AND P.Categoria=1
```

Pero yo no necesito quitar el `string` y la letra `P`, para que quede de la siguiente manera.

```
AND Categoria=1
```

Ya trate haciendo lo siguiente y si me quita el punto pero no logro quitar la letra P

```
int filtroadicional = DR["FiltroAdicional"].ToString().IndexOf(".");
string s = (string)DR["FiltroAdicional"].ToString().Substring(0, filtroadicional);
string f = (string)DR["FiltroAdicional"].ToString().Substring(filtroadicional + 1);
```

agradeceria mucho su ayuda.

Saludos

Comment: `string s = (string)DR["FiltroAdicional"].ToString().Substring(0, filtroadicional-1);`?

Comment: ¿qué tal (string)DR["FiltroAdicional"].ToString().Remove(0, 2)?

Answer (score 2):

Hola puedes intentar con esto:

```
string result = "";
string str = "AND P.Categoria=1";

var split = str.Split(".");
var splitLeft = split[0].Split(" ");
result = string.Format("{0} {1}", splitLeft[0], split[1]);
```

Aunque es preferible que solamente recibas el parametro asi no tienes que estar trabajando con string y tu puedes definir el alias y no esperarlo como parte de la solicitud:

```
int category = 1;
string query = string.Format("AND Categoria={0}",category);
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar el reemplazo de expresión regular:

```
var f = Regex.Replace(filtro, @"(\w+)\s+\w+\.(\w+)\s*=\s*(\w+)", "${1} ${2}=${3}");
```

La expresión regular anterior captura en primer lugar el operador (`AND` en tu ejemplo) a continuación lo que haya después del punto (`Categoria` en tu ejemplo) y para finalizar lo que haya después de la igualación (`1` en tu ejemplo).

Después lo substituye en la forma que buscas: "*Operador nombre=valor*". Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TU1Na8JAFDxnf8Wy5JA0dUF7DAGL7U2LWMFD08NjfSwLMSvvrTYS9reni3jwMMwMzIfhmfGE03Rh11v5feOAp1o8O73HIegd2ksH9DmcCZmd77kWwnTALLfkLcFJjCLjAMEZefXuKDfg@oIDpaWfXwlkuRRZymSrVPYd6gO5gGvXY5HGcUgX5w4MFur960Nu9QoCWk8Omrl6lUtVtH9V2XKVqNUP89Ik3HWKqHycR5mPi9jk41tUZVmLLIo4Tf8)</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

No hace falta que castees dos veces la string, quizás te sirva un replace:

`string s = DR["FiltroAdicional"].ToString().Replace("P.","");`

Saludos!

Comment: Con el caso de ejemplo, esta sería una muy buena solución. Pero imagino que no siempre es una `P` lo que recibe el OP, sino cualquier otra letra

Comment: Si, en caso de que sean distintas tablas le conviene la opción de Bird. En el caso de que solo sean de P optaría por esta opción que es más comprensible